# application unable to access internet on device while working properly on android emulator?

Tags: android, sip, user-permissions

I have developed one SIP based application which is not able to use an internet connection while debugging on an android device. But when debugging on the emulator it works properly. I have given all the permissions in manifest.xml regarding internet connection. Is there any other permission to use the internet connection to run an application on the device? here i have attached my manifest.xml.Any help and suggestions will be appreciated.
`

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sip.voip" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon64" android:label="SipDemo" android:debuggable="true">
   <activity android:name=".WalkieTalkieActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity> 
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".WalkieTalkieActivity"/>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".Services"/>

    <activity android:name=".WalkieTalkieActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SipSettings" android:label="set_preferences"/>
     <activity android:name=".dialer" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
     <activity android:name=".timer" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
     <activity android:name=".d1" android:label="@string/app_name"/>

    <receiver android:name=".IncomingCallReceiver" android:label="Call Receiver" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
</application>
```

`

Comment: Can you post the permissions you have in your manifest already so we can see what you've tried?  Welcome to SO!

Comment: @C.Barlow: thanking to your response. here i am attaching my manifest.xml. please verify it.

Comment: @Jack : thanking to your response. here i am attaching my manifest.xml. please verify it.

Answer (score 0):

To access Internet the only **Uses Permission** needed is **android.permission.INTERNET** in Manifest. Please Check your Internet connectivity with a Browser in Phone first.

Comment: @Periyasam :thanks for your reply. but i had verified my INTERNET Connection on device. even other applications works properly on device.I have tested the INTERNET connection throgh SipDroid and Fring applications.it works properly.i am using android version 2.3.3