# SIP outgoing call is not ended properly

Tags: android, sip, phone-call

In my application when i am making a outgoing call and if i ended it from my application its ended properly but when call receiver ends that call, sometimes it ends sometimes its not.

i debug the application many times and came to know that sometimes call goes into onEndCall() method and sometimes it does not.if call goes into this method it works fine.so what could be the reason for that?

I am using Android 2.3.3 and Asterisk 1.8.10.0

Comment: Check pkt. Asterisk send proper BYE message for both case?

Comment: yeah i am getting a BYE packet properly. what could be the reason of this problem? should i use a external SIP stack library to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are experiencing a similar issue as me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875935/android-2-3-4-sipaudiocall-listener-oncallestablished-not-firing-every-time

Even in your case I think that the Listener that you connect to incoming calls (which are passed from the call receiver to your activity) is not always firing the methods. Therefore the call is closed in your application, but not in asterisk / on the other device.

I am sorry that I can't give you a solution, I am stuck by myself with this problem...
Best Regards,

Armin

**EDIT 02/04/2012:** 
I have now - just for curiosity - changed VoIP server using the 3CX software and I am not able to reproduce the problem anymore!!! Maybe there is something in the replies of asterisk that causes the strange behavior! I will now start some wireshark tests to understand the difference between the messages of asterisk and 3CX and keep you updated!

Comment: @Armin yeah exactly.but if you get any solution please let me inform. thanks

Comment: Sure I will, same for you please! ;-)

Comment: @juned, I have updated my post, please check it out. If you have time, you could also make a try with 3CX in order to check if also your problems are purely related to asterisk.

Comment: thanks for your answer.i will let you inform once i finish the trial with 3CX.And currently i moves to Sipdroid project for analysis and to add some extra features in my SIP application.

Comment: i have another issue regarding this project,please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513943/application-unable-to-access-internet-on-device-while-working-properly-on-androi and let me know had you face this problem?

Comment: Hi juned,
what's the exact error you are getting? 
And on which kind of device are you trying? A device with WiFi internet connection, 3G or LAN based connection? I had similar problems on devices with no WiFi / no SIP - VoIP support!

Comment: my application works fine but always i am getting a manager=null(manager=SipManager) when its on INTERNET,GPRS or EDGE network, while on wifi network it works properly.what could be the reason?

Comment: For what I know, the implemented SIP API should work also with other connections, but take care: as soon as you use your mobile data connections, you will be in another network, so the local VoIP server can't be reached anymore. So you will have to provide another IP or a STUN server to register correctly... at leats that's what I'm thinking...